# barplot position is not working correctly

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am trying to make a grouped barplot in ggplot2, but it keeps coming out as a stacked plot, which I do not want. Below are my code and the results.

```
library(ggplot2)

# Create dataframe
exons <- data.frame(nucleotide = c("A", "C", "G", "T"),
                 first.exon = c(18, 28, 33, 21),
                 internal.exon = c(25, 28, 26, 21),
                 last.exon = c(26, 22, 23, 29))

# Plot variables
ggplot(data = exons, aes(x = nucleotide)) + 
  geom_col(aes(y = first.exon, fill = "First Exon"), position = "dodge") + 
  geom_col(aes(y = internal.exon, fill = "Internal Exon"), position = "dodge") + 
  geom_col(aes(y = last.exon, fill = "Last Exon"), position = "dodge") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("First Exon" = "blue",
                               "Internal Exon" = "green",
                               "Last Exon" = "red")) + 
  labs(title = "Number of Nucleotides in Each Exon",
       x = "Nucleotide",
       y = "Counts",
       fill = "") + 
  theme_minimal()
```

This is the graph I am getting- it is stacked, not grouped, but the position is set to "dodge", so I am not sure why it is not working.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the grouped bar plot you can reshape your data where all the exon columns are gathered into a single column named 'exon' and all values from the three exon columns are gathered into a single column names 'values'. Then it is possible to plot a bar plot by grouping variable (nucleotide) :

```
  # reshape your data into longer format and relevel the exon 
  # levels as you prefer in the order you want using 
  # factor() function

library(tidyverse)
exons %>% pivot_longer(values_to = 'values',names_to = 'exons',cols = all_of(names(exons)[2:4])) %>% 
  mutate(exons=factor(exons,levels=c('first.exon','internal.exon','last.exon'))) %>%

# create bar plot by grouping factor(nucleotide)
ggplot( aes(fill=exons, y=values, x=nucleotide)) + 
  
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.title =element_blank())+ # remove the legend title
  #create bar plot
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") +
  # change the colors based on your exon levels and rename legend 
  # labels
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue","green","red"), labels = c('First Exon', 'Internal Exon','Last Exon'))+
# move the legend position to the top to make more space 
  theme(legend.position = 'top',legend.direction = 'horizontal')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to reshape that data from wide to long using `tidyr::pivot_longer`. This makes passing the correct information to `aes()` much easier.

Note that by default the column names generated by `pivot_longer` for the variable and its value are "name" and "value", respectively.

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

exons %>% 
  pivot_longer(-nucleotide) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(nucleotide, value)) + 
  geom_col(aes(fill = name), 
           position = position_dodge())
```

Result:

[image]